# How to stop/handle random HTML popup during test execution - Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium

I'm hoping someone would be able to help me with my query. I've done quite a bit of research online and haven't found any particular solution to it yet.

While running my test case, I sometimes encounter an HTML popup that I'm unable to handle in my script. It is very random (well based on customer behaviour while they are traversing the site) and can popup at any time during the customer journey. Sometimes it doesn't popup at all. When it appears only then an entry is visible inside the DOM.

Basically, it is a livechat window (LivePerson to be precise) suggesting customers that an agent is available to help them complete their order if they wish to do so.

Here is a screenshot:

[popup screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4Hth.png)

The below is available in Firebug when I inspect the element:

```
<div id="LPMcontainer-1483053256847-0" class="LPMcontainer LPMoverlay" style="margin: -143px 0px 0px -285px; padding: 0px; border-style: solid; border-width: 0px; outline-color: rgb(106, 159, 177); outline-width: 2px; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; font-variant: normal; list-style: outside none none; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: normal; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: normal; word-spacing: normal; background-repeat: repeat-x; background-position: left bottom; background-color: transparent; border-color: transparent; width: 571px; height: 287px; cursor: pointer; display: block; z-index: 107158; position: fixed; top: 50%; bottom: auto; left: 50%; right: auto;">
 <div role="button" tabindex="0"><img src="https://www./content/dam/tcom/apps/live-person/live-person-chat-bundles-top.jpg" id="LPMimage-1483053256849-2" alt="" class="LPMimage" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-style: none; border-width: 0px; outline-color: rgb(106, 159, 177); outline-width: 2px; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; font-variant: normal; list-style: outside none none; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: normal; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: normal; word-spacing: normal; position: absolute; z-index: 600; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
</div>
 <img src="https://www./content/dam/tcom/apps/live-person/live-person-chat-bottom.jpg" id="LPMcloseButton-1483053256847-1" alt="" class="LPMcloseButton" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-style: none; border-width: 0px; outline-color: rgb(106, 159, 177); outline-width: 2px; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; font-variant: normal; list-style: outside none none; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: normal; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: normal; word-spacing: normal; position: absolute; cursor: pointer; z-index: 9999; left: 0px; top: 194px;" data-lp-event="close" role="button" tabindex="0">
</div>
```

It appears in all browsers.

I'd like to handle it in either of the following ways:

1. Stop it from loading at all (again due to random nature ).
   OR
2. While the script is being executed, as soon as the window appears, it presses 'No thanks' button (id="LPMcloseButton-1483053256847-1" in the above code) and then continue executing the rest of the steps. Please note that id is dynamic in nature, i.e it's unique every time.

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be random. Some sites that I write automation for have something like this also. After some investigation I found that the dialog always popped up after 30 seconds... it just seemed random because I could be on any page when the 30s was up. After more investigation I found that the site looked for a cookie and if it wasn't found, the dialog would be triggered. I found the cookie that was created *after* the dialog was closed and created it at the start of the script so that it would no longer open.

I would suggest that you look for an existing cookie that was created for that site and see what's in it. Then browse to the site, wait for the dialog to pop up, and close it. See what changes... if the cookie changes or a new cookie is added, etc. then just mimic that behavior before browsing the site.

NOTE: In my case, I had to intentionally browse to a missing page on the domain, e.g. somesite.com/someerrorpage, to create the cookie without the timer starting. Then I just navigated to the site and continued the script.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeff. That is very handy to know. I'll try the way you've suggested. My gut feeling says that this may work in my case as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the easiest way to get around this is to create a webdriver wrapper that for every call you would send to webdriver, first check if the dialog is present. If it's present, close it, otherwise send the action over to webdriver.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, Lucas. If I could please ask, can you provide an example. I'm learning Java and Selenium at the same time so you'd need to hold my hand a little bit longer :-)

Comment: I'm afraid I'm of no assistance for Java. I only do Python/Ruby